# Robot framework rfswarm usage

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, robotframework, performance-testing

[https://github.com/damies13/rfswarm  I try to do performance-stress test of my web app. I used robot framework for the basic test create new user, block user tests etc. When I start to run my test app is stopped working. What I'm doing wrong?

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RRqnw.png when I select any test option give me error related with agents
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/olFur.png

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem before, but I finally figured it out.

**You need to select a test** https://i.stack.imgur.com/NYmsh.jpg, not just only select script